# Can't generate unix socket deploying django project

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi

I'm trying to deploy my first django project, i'm using uwsgi and nginx on a linode server.
Basically I follow the next steps.

1. Create uwsgi config file for my project on /etc/uwsgi/apps-available/, and create the symbolic link on /etc/uwsgi/apps-enabled/:

   ```
   [uwsgi]
   plugins = http,python
   env = DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=app.settings
   chdir = /opt/deploy/.virtualenvs/test_app/test/
   home = /opt/deploy/.virtualenvs/test_app/
   module = django.core.handlers.wsgi:WSGIHandler()
   processes = 4
   idle = 3600
   touch-reload = /opt/deploy/.virtualenvs/test_app/test/app/local_settings.py
   ```
2. Create my nginx config file on /etc/nginx/sites-available/ and create the symbolic link in cd nginx/sites-enabled/, this is my nginx file:

   ```
   server {
       server_name  www.test.com;
       rewrite ^(.*) http://test.com$1 permanent;
   }
   server {
       listen       80;
       server_name  test.com;
       charset      utf-8;

       client_max_body_size       10m;
       client_body_buffer_size    128k;

       # serve static files
       location /static/ {
           alias /opt/deploy/.virtualenvs/test_app/test/app/static/;
       }

       location / {
           include        uwsgi_params;
           uwsgi_pass     unix:/run/uwsgi/app/test.sock;
       }
   }
   ```
3. Restart uwsgi and nginx.

I expect find the file test.sock on run/uwsgi/app/, but the file is not created. When a see the nignx error log I have this line:

```
2015/10/02 01:47:49 [crit] 8967#0: *51 connect() to unix:/run/uwsgi/app/test.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 181.135.143.435, server: test.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:/run/uwsgi/app/test.sock:", host: "test.com"
```

Why can i do for generate the uwsgi file?, thankyou so much I know that could be a stupid question but before to do this write a look for a lot of tutorials and can't find any solution.. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you need some special permissions to generate the socket file on the location /run/uwsgi/app/. If you put it in /tmp/test.sock, the socket should be generated correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a part in your config. Here is a working config from my server:

```
upstream django-myhome {
    server unix:///home/myhome/myhome/myhome.sock; # for a file socket
}
server
    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  django-myhome;
        include     /home/myhome/myhome/uwsgi_params; # the uwsgi_params file you installed
    }
```

Be also sure that you have the right permissions to create the .sock file